# remote build on openshift jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, openshift

I am trying to invoke remote build with token. It gives me 401. As per my understanding its not required with token.

```
Jigars-MacBook-Pro:portal jigarshah$ 
curl https://jigarshah:<TOKEN API>@jenkins-jigarshah.rhcloud.com/job/MyJob/build?token=<TOKEN>

<html><head><title>Error 401</title></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1>Status Code: 401</h1>Exception: Bad credentials<br>Stacktrace: (none)
<br><hr size="1" width="90%"><i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Mon Apr 08 09:27:59 EDT 2013</i></body></html>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You forget about your username and password.

Look this: [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) and [link](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+Jenkins+using+HTTP+Basic+Authentication)

Comment: Oh dear...that's an issue...how bitbucket service hooks will able to pass that information ? as per first link  wget http://user:apiToken@jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN should work. apiToken which is equivalent to password is already there....

Comment: This format worked for me:
curl -3 https://admin:PASSWORD@jenkins-macdomain.rhcloud.com/job/simpleapp-build/build?t...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I don't have to provide password. Just API TOKEN is good enough. Yes, user name has to me from jenkins. go to /me/configure

There is button that says "show api token". Use that to trigger build...

curl https://:@/job/MyJob/build?token=

Comment: ~"There is button that says 'show api token'".  Where is this button you are talking about?